# python type errors in lists

Tags: list, typeerror, indices

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df['final_grade'] = 'na'

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

df['final_grade'] = 'na'

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you are assigning a string to `df['final_grade'] = 'na'` instead you should assign integer to it.